# Entity framework 6 after updating foreign key navigation property returning null

Tags: c#, .net, entity, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

I am using Entity framework 6 in my project. I have a parent class Student which has navigation Class.
When i am changing Class navigation property and call SaveChanges().Everything is working fine. Foreign key is getting updated in Student table but when i click the load student button navigation property is returning null. I have disabled lazy loading by removing virtual keyword on Class navigation property and updated DBContext with below line.

```
 this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

and updated repository as well

```
 public IEnumerable<Students> GetAll()
 {
     return base.objDBSet.Include("Class").ToList();
 }
```

Entire application is using single instance of dbContext which i persist using Singleton pattern. If i restart the project then all updated navigation properties have Class instance. Please suggest why dbcontext is returning null after SaveChanges() without restarting project. Is it okay to have single instance of Dbcontext or i should create different instances of Dbcontext on each request?